# Adding a linear gradient to Material UI icon

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, material-design

I've tried the process described in this question [Trying to add linear gradient to a martialUI icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65051364/trying-to-add-linear-gradient-to-a-martialui-icon) as a comment stated it should work, but it does not for me.

Thinking that maybe the icons counted as text, I've tried several of the ways to add gradients to text such as here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/gradient-text/.

Yet I haven't gotten anything to work. The gradient either shows as a box image in the foreground, in front of the icon, or just not at all. Does anyone know how to add a gradient to Material UI icons?

EDIT: Forgot to post my code, here's the relevant snippet:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
root: {
  display: 'flex',
},
appBar: {
  zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
},
drawer: {
  width: drawerWidth,
  flexShrink: 0
},
drawerPaper: {
  width: drawerWidth,
  backgroundColor:muiTheme.palette.secondary.main
},
drawerContainer: {
  overflow: 'auto',
  background:muiTheme.palette.secondary.main
},
content: {
  flexGrow: 1,
  padding: theme.spacing(3),
},
sideBarButton: {
    fill: "#FFFFFF",
    fontSize: "50px"
}
  }));



const SideBar = (props) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={muiTheme}>
            <Drawer
                className={classes.drawer}
                variant="permanent"
                classes={{
                paper: classes.drawerPaper,
                }}
            >
            <Toolbar />
            <div className={classes.drawerContainer}>
                <Box display="flex" flexDirection="column" padding="0" margin="0"   >
                <List>
                    <ListItem button>
                        <ListItemIcon> <SearchIcon className={classes.sideBarButton}/> </ListItemIcon>
                        <ListItemText/>
                    </ListItem>
                    <ListItem button>
                        <ListItemIcon> <AddCircleIcon className={classes.sideBarButton}/> </ListItemIcon>
                        <ListItemText/>
                    </ListItem>
                </List>
                </Box>
            </div>
            </Drawer>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    )
}
```

More precisely, this is the list item (which is a material icon) I'm trying to add gradient to:

```
<ListItemIcon> 
    <SearchIcon className{classes.sideBarButton}/> 
</ListItemIcon>
```

And this is the style applied:

```
sideBarButton: {
    background: "linear-gradient(to right, #ad5389, #3c1053)",
    fontSize: "50px"
}
```

The other methods I've tried per the links above:

```
// Just put the style in the tag, doesn't compile
<SearchIcon className={classes.sideBarButton} style={{linear-gradient(to right bottom, #FD297B, #FF5864, #FF655B)}}/>
```

Another method:

```
    sideBarButton:{
     background: "-webkit-linear-gradient(#eee, #333)",
     WebkitBackgroundClip: "text",
     WebkitTextFillColor: "transparent",
     fontSize: "50px"
    }
```

Yet another method via https://fossheim.io/writing/posts/css-text-gradient/ :

```
 sideBarButton:{
        /* Create the gradient. */
     backgroundImage: "linear-gradient(45deg, #f3ec78, #af4261)",

    /* Set the background size and repeat properties. */
    backgroundSize: "100%",
    backgroundRepeat: "repeat",

    /* Use the text as a mask for the background. */
    /* This will show the gradient as a text color rather than element bg. */
    WebkitBackgroundClip: "text",
    WebkitTextFillColor: "transparent",
    MozBackgroundClip: "text",
    MozTextFillColor: "transparent",
    fontSize: "50px"
    }
```

P.S. I'm just now learning React, I may very well be missing something simple. Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: @MCA Ah, sorry about that, just edited with code and more clear info about what I've tried so far.

Comment: specifically, where do you want to add a gradient in background color or in icon color?

Comment: @Rajiv I would like the fill of the Search Icon to be a gradient, the background should be transparent. It's worth mentioning, I've also tried "fill : "linear-gradient(to right, #ad5389, #3c1053)" as well in my code, but this also did not affect the icon any, so I assume it is not valid React code.

Comment: Also, I know it isn't any thing wrong with the structure of my code elsewhere, because if I do something simple like "fill : "blue" " or "background: "blue" ", then the icon is changed as one would expect.

Comment: for using gradient in SVG fill `linearGradient ` needs to be used in SVG, I guess

Comment: @Rajiv Hey thanks for replying! I wasn't actually quite sure what you meant, but Googling my issue with the "SVG" keyword led me to this GitHub issue: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/9496 and the answer at the bottom gave me a good base to edit and give me what I wanted. I''ll probably update my post with an answer soon for future reference, but if you want to create an answer with more info I'd accept it if you want.

Comment: it is quite helpful. have you tried this method on other icons provided by `@material-ui`?

Comment: Hi @Rajiv, yes I tried the method I found in the Github issue with a few other icons and can confirm it works.

Answer (score 13):

Here is an example using Material UI v5.

The fill property of the icon is linked to the [linear gradient's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/linearGradient) id property.

```
import OpenWithIcon from "@material-ui/icons/OpenWith"

const GradientOpenWithIcon = () => (
  <>
    <svg width={0} height={0}>
      <linearGradient id="linearColors" x1={1} y1={0} x2={1} y2={1}>
        <stop offset={0} stopColor="rgba(241,184,74,1)" />
        <stop offset={1} stopColor="rgba(207,113,8,1)" />
      </linearGradient>
    </svg>
    <OpenWithIcon sx={{ fill: "url(#linearColors)" }} />
  </>
)
```

Comment: Not sure why but this only sometimes works for me (when it does, it works great). half the time all my icons just show up black, refreshing the page fixes it.